# C# + Castle ActiveRecord: HasAndBelongsToMany and collections

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, hql, castle-activerecord

Let's say I have many-to-many relationship (using the ActiveRecord attribute HasAndBelongsToMany) between Posts and Tags (domain object names changed to protect the innocent), and I wanted a method like

```
FindAllPostByTags(IList<Tag> tags)
```

that returns all Posts that have all (not just some of) the Tags in the parameter. Any way I could accomplish this either with NHibernate Expressions or HQL? I've searched through the HQL documentation and couldn't find anything that suited my needs. I hope I'm just missing something obvious!

Comment: Is there any answer below that works for you? If so, do the one who answered it a favor, and accept it. You'll also get more rep yourself by doing that

Comment: This was so long ago that I don't exactly remember, but I think I eventually just took a different approach, or worked around it. I wish I had thought of submitting it as an answer though. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also just use an `IN` statement

```
DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.For<Post>();
query.CreateCriteria("Post").Add(Expression.In("TagName",  string.Join(",",tags.ToArray()) );
```

I haven't compiled that so it could have errors

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a system at hand with a Castle install right now, so I didn't test or compile this, but the code below should about do what you want.

```
Junction c = Expression.Conjunction();
foreach(Tag t in tags)
    c = c.Add( Expression.Eq("Tag", t);

return sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(Post)).Add(c).List();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and tried to read the HQL-documentation, however some of the features doesn't seem to be implemented in NHibernate (with-keyword for example)

I ended up with this sort of solution:

```
select p 
FROM Post p
JOIN p.Tags tag1
JOIN p.Tags tag2
WHERE
    tag1.Id = 1
    tag2.Id = 2
```

Meaning, dynamically build the HQL using join for each tag, then make the selection in your WHERE clause. This worked for me. I tried doing the same thing with a DetachedCriteria but ran into trouble when trying to join the table multiple times.